# Ant get the value of a parameter obtained at runtime

Tags: ant

I have an Ant build task where in based I need to  lookup the property file based on a value which I get at runtime. For example, I have the following information in property file

```
COMPLETE_LIST=TEST1,TEST2,TEST3
TEST1=val1
TEST2=val2
TEST3=val3
```

In my Ant target, I have the following task.

```
<target name="target_main">
    <foreach param="profile_name" list="${COMPLETE_LIST}" target="target_child">
    </foreach>
</target>

<target name="target_child">
<echo>Printing the value of the param passed ${${profile_name}}</echo>
</target>
```

But this is not working. Is there any way to get the value of `TEST1` which is passed as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already are using [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/index.html), the [propertycopy](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertycopy.html) task will help you do what you want. Here's the body of `target_child` modified to suit your purpose:

```
<target name="target_child">
  <propertycopy name="value" from="${profile_name}"/>
  <echo>Printing the value of the param passed ${${profile_name}}</echo>
</target>
```

The output:

```
target_main:

target_child:
     [echo] Printing the value of the param passed val1

target_child:
     [echo] Printing the value of the param passed val2

target_child:
     [echo] Printing the value of the param passed val3
```